# Javascript Document.Refferer

Tags: javascript

Could someone tell me why this wont work?
Its a script to get the referred page that got you to the current page...

```
<script>
function ref()
{
var x = "Reffered From: " + document.referrer;
document.getElementById("reff").value=x;
}
</script>

<body onload="ref()">

<p id="reff"></p>
```

Comment: The "referrer" thing is quite unreliable and really shouldn't be used if you can possibly find an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Only form control elements have a `value` property. You are looking for `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("reff").innerHTML = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementById("reff").value=x;
```

should be

```
 document.getElementById("reff").innerHTML=x;
```

Answer (score 1):

1.use .value when you try to fetch something from an input.

```
var x = document.getElementById("reff").value;alert(x)..returns 5
<input type=text id="reff" value="5">
```

2.use [innerHTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)L for getting the content of an element.

```
var para_content = document.getElementById("reff").innerHTML;//alert(para_content)
<p id="reff"> Hii ,I am para </p>
```